# Make saturday and sunday unselectable in HTML <input type="date" ...>

Tags: html

We have a datepicker in our mvc asp.net core application.
But i want to make saturday and sunday unselectable in it is this possible?
Thanks in advance.
Joni

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Comment: Can you specify the name of datepicker you are using ,Some of them have a option to disable specific days.

Comment: It is just the standard datepicker of the html input

Comment: <input type="date" id="dat" class="form-control" name="dat" min="@DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")" max="" required="required" />

Comment: @SushrutSinghSisodiya

Answer (score 0):

Yes possible, you can do this with bootstrap date picker

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
   Date : <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control datepicker" autocomplete="off">
</div>
  
</body>
   
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,6]
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: if it works mark this as right answer and up vote it as per @JoniTimmermans